# Get a static property of an instance

Tags: php, oop, static, late-binding, class-variables

If I have an instance in PHP, what's the easiest way to get to a static property ('class variable') of that instance ?

This

```
$classvars=get_class_vars(get_class($thing));
$property=$classvars['property'];
```

Sound really overdone. I would expect

```
$thing::property
```

or

```
$thing->property
```

> EDIT: this is an old question. There are more obvious ways to do this in newer
>   PHP, search below.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to lookup the class name first:

```
$class = get_class($thing);
$class::$property
```

$property must be defined as `static` and `public` of course.

Comment: Confirmed, that works , php 5.3.0> ... still a bit overdone, but i guess this is the shortest. thanks !

Comment: No, "As of PHP 5.3.0, it's possible to reference the class using a variable".

Answer (score 10):

From inside a class instance you can simply use `self::...`

```
class Person {
  public static $name = 'Joe';
  public function iam() {
    echo 'My name is ' . self::$name;
  }
}

$me = new Person();
$me->iam(); // displays "My name is Joe"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you'd rather not

```
$class = get_class($instance);
$var = $class::$staticvar;
```

because you find its two lines too long, you have other options available:

#### 1. Write a getter

```
<?php
class C {
  static $staticvar = "STATIC";
  function getTheStaticVar() {
    return self::$staticvar;
  }
}
$instance = new C();
echo $instance->getTheStaticVar();
```

Simple and elegant, but you'd have to write a getter for every static variable you're accessing.

#### 2. Write a universal static-getter

```
<?php
class C {
  static $staticvar = "STATIC";
  function getStatic($staticname) {
    return self::$$staticname;
  }
}
$instance = new C();
echo $instance->getStatic('staticvar');
```

This will let you access any static, though it's still a bit long-winded.

#### 3. Write a magic method

```
class C {
  static $staticvar = "STATIC";
  function __get($staticname) {
    return self::$$staticname;
  }
}
$instance = new C();
echo $instance->staticvar;
```

This one allows you instanced access to any static variable as if it were a local variable of the object, but it may be considered an unholy abomination.

Comment: Oh, and remember to use `static::$$staticname` if you extend this class and want to use the subclass' statics, not the parent's.

Answer (score 1):

```
classname::property;
```

I think that's it.

Answer (score 1):

You access them using the double colon (or the [`T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM` token](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php) if you prefer)

```
class X {
    public static $var = 13;
}
echo X::$var;
```

[Variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) are supported here, too:

```
$class = 'X';
echo $class::$var;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should understand what the static property means. Static property or method is not for the objects. They are directly used by the class.

you can access them by

```
Class_name::static_property_name
```

Comment: A static property is a property of the class, and hence meaningful information for all instances .. in all languages except php :-)

Comment: @pike: That's true but they are not bounded with any specific instance

Answer (score 1):

These days, there is a pretty simple, clean way to do this.

```
<?php
namespace Foo;
class Bar
{
    public static $baz=1;
    //...

    public function __toString()
    {
        return self::class;
    }

}

echo Bar::$baz; // returns 1
$bar = new Bar();
echo $bar::$baz; // returns 1
```

You can also do this with a property in PHP 7.

```
<?php
namespace Foo;
class Bar
{
    public static $baz=1;
    public $class=self::class;
    //...

}

$bar = new Bar();
echo $bar->class::$baz; // returns 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class testClass {
    public static $property = "property value";
    public static $property2 = "property value 2";
}
echo testClass::$property;
echo testClass::property2;
```