# Access Static properties using PHP object

Tags: php, static

This is with reference to [Get a static property of an instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623846/get-a-static-property-of-an-instance), I am a newbie and have the following code :

```
class Foo
{
   public static $my_static = 1;
}

class Bar extends Foo
{

}

$foo = new Foo();
$boo = new Bar();

echo Foo::$my_static;  // ok
echo Bar::$my_static;  // ok
echo $foo::$my_static; // ok
echo $boo::$my_static; // ok
```

Static variables/properties are accessed only as **ClassName::static_property** as in C++, but it is not the case in PHP... but PHP books mostly mention the **className::static_property** pattern, not the **object::static_property** construct. Need more light on this..

Comment: also, from inside a class you may use `self::$my_static` or `static::$my_static` (see [late static bindings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) for the `static::` usage (since PHP 5.3)

Comment: check this link it may help... http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Static properties may be accessed on various ways.

```
Class::$aStaticProp; //by class name

$classname::$aStaticProp; // As of PHP 5.3.0 by object instance
```

Static properties cannot be accessed through the object using the arrow operator `->`.

As of PHP 5.3.0, it's possible to reference the class using a variable. The variable's value can not be a keyword (e.g. self, parent and static).

More you can read in [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Answer (score 12):

`$instance::$staticProperty` is simply a convenience shorthand for `Class::$staticProperty`. Since you already have an instance of a *class* and the syntax is unambiguous, PHP saves you from writing a potentially long class name. There's no functional difference.

Comment: I do have a followup annoyance, since I'm a bit in disbelief that this works: `$instance::$staticProperty` does not make sense to me.  The static property belongs to the class, not the object.  Why does the interpreter allow this to slide for 'convenience'?

Comment: Sometimes when you hold name of classes in strings and you're doing dynamic operations of them it's very useful.

Comment: @Robert I guess it should make sense to me because PHP isn't the strictest of languages, but you could simply use `get_class()` to get the object's class name.

Comment: @BLaZuRE `$foo::$bar` → *"Get the static property `$bar` of the class `$foo` is an instance of."* It's just syntactic sugar and seems mightily convenient to me. :-3

Answer (score 3):

within the class you have to use like self::$staticPropery
if the function accessing to the variable is also static.